# "Proudly Sydney Based": To hyphenate or not?

Tags: hyphenation

I want to check my understanding (or lack of it) about hyphenation. I find hyphens very confusing.
I have a phrase "Proudly Sydney Based" for a headline.
My understanding is that as written above there is no hyphen, but if I wrote a "Sydney-based company" I would need to use a hyphen.
Can you please advise whether this is correct?

Comment: Adverbs ending in *ly* are not normally hyphenated with the word that follows them. Plus, in this case, if you *were* to hyphenate anything, it would be the last two words. But there is no room for confusion here, so, on multiple levels, a hyphen is not needed. (On the other hand, somebody who wrote it as *Proudly Sydney-Based* would not be wrong.)

Comment: Could you take basic queries about the use of hyphens to somewhere like English Language Learners?

Answer (score -2):

First, hyphens must never be used interchangeably with dashes (see the Dashes section link given below), which are noticeably longer. Second, there should not be spaces around hyphens.

Incorrect: 300—325 people
Incorrect: 300 - 325 people
Correct: 300-325 people

and in your case :

Proudly Sydney-Based is correct and no more anxiety about it,must used as headline.

***reference:***https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp